# Validar textarea, al tener mas de 50 caracteres, eliminarlos y quedarme solo con los 50 primeros

Tags: javascript

Quiero a la hora de introducir un texto en un textarea, con JavaScript, poder obtener los 50 primeros caracteres de ese string y el resto no almacenarlos.
La idea es que la persona que esté introduciendo el texto, pueda seguir escribiendo, pero que al enviar los datos en el formulario, solo se almacenen los 50 primeros caracteres y el resto se omitan.

He estado investigando y encontré esto en developer Mozilla, pero no soy capaz a dar con la solución.

```
cadena.slice(inicioTrozo[, finTrozo])
```

Muchas gracias a todos.

Comment: Intenta poner el atributo `maxlength="50"` a la etiqueta. Si lo quieres hacer con Javascript, puedes usar [.substring()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring)

Comment: Sí, la idea es hacerlo con JS, gracias por tu aporte, finalmente utilicé substring(), un saludo y muchas gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tienes 3 opciones para conseguir lo que quieres:

1. El método `slice`. El primer parámetro que acepta es desde dónde empiezas a contar y el segundo es hasta dónde cuentas, sin incluir.
2. El método `substring`. Funciona igual que slice, pero es específico de `String` (slice existe en `Array`).
3. El método `substr`. Este toma como primer valor desde donde quieres empezar y como segundo valor, cuántos caracteres quieres obtener.

Debes considerar que todos estos métodos DEVUELVEN uno nuevo, entonces para poder obtenerlo, debes almacenarlo en una variable.

```javascript
// 1era opción
const varSlice = cadena.slice(0, 50);

// 2da opción
const varSubstring = cadena.substring(0, 50);

// 3ra opción
const varSubstr = cadena.substr(0, 50);
```

Te recomiendo utilizar `substring`. Saludos y coméntanos cómo te va.

Comment: Pues me fué genial tu ayuda. Mucho mejor explicado que el propio developer Mozilla, agradezco tu tiempo y ayuda. Algún dia devolveré a la comunidad de StackOverflow toda esta ayuda en estos inicios en el mundillo de la programación.

Comment: Genial!!! No dudes en buscar ayuda y contribuir en lo que puedas, tanto en internet como con tus colegas de trabajo. Feliz viaje!

Comment: Hola, si esta pregunta fue respondida por favor, acepta la respuesta como válida para cerrarla. Gracias!